# JBehave & Serenity - skip scenarios in story after fail

Tags: jbehave, serenity-bdd

I have:
Story:
Scenario 1.
Scenario 2.
Scenario 3.

I would like to skip scenarios 2 and 3 if scenario 1 has failed.
I am using jbehave and Serenity.

I am starting my tests like this:

```
 public RunTestSuite() {
        findStoriesCalled(storyNamesFromEnvironmentVariable());
    }
```

I tried 
configuration().storyControls().doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(true);
but it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

Create separate class have a variable like "**int** FlowIndicator;" or "**boolean** FlowIndicator;" have a getter and setter for it.

Now in the story class assign value for it this FlowIndicator.

Like if the Scenarios 1 is pass FlowIndicator should 1 or true
If Scenario 1 is fail FlowIndicator should be 0 or false.

That way you can have the verification in Scenario 2 and 3 for FlowIndicator should be 1.